# SSH login hangs for several minutes

Tags: ssh

SSH login will hang on Entering interactive session for several minutes.

```
debug3: muxserver_listen: mux listener channel 0 fd 4
debug1: channel 1: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 1
debug2: channel 1: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

My sshd_config:

```
Port 22
AddressFamily inet
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
MaxSessions 10
IgnoreRhosts yes
PasswordAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
UseDNS no
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What's the load on the server?

Comment: Essentially nothing.

Comment: I would take a look at what network communication is happening on the server. Maybe it is waiting for some network service to respond during that time.

Comment: Check if the remote server is doing quota checks when you log in.by calling `/sbin/quotacheck` from `/etc/profile` or something similar.

Comment: Try logging in one session and then starting a second session. You should be able to identify the new sshd process (`ps -eaf | grep sshd`) and then look at its children to see what is taking the time.

Comment: @PaulHaldane OH, ok, it's stuck reading `/var/log/btmp`. The file is huge (4GB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try logging in one session and then starting a second session. You should be able to identify the new sshd process (`ps -eaf | grep sshd`) and then look at its children to see what is taking the time.

That showed that it was busy reading a huge (4GB) `/var/log/btmp`.

Adding something like

```
/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    minsize 1M
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

to `/etc/logrotate.conf` would rotate `btmp` monthly and hopefully avoid the issue. If your `btmp` file is getting to 4GB in a month then you might need to look at `fail2ban` or similar to minimise the effect of brute force attacks (or you could just rotate the file more frequently).

Comment: It isn't that easy, as you need to use `strace` and `lsof`, but yes.